# How to subtract or minus from two array of objects particular values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

To be silly I am here to ask a simple question which make me too much time 
Here is sample data

```
    const demo1 = [
       { count: 156, monthCount: 1, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 165, monthCount: 2, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 103, monthCount: 3, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 60, monthCount: 4, year: 2018 }
    ]
    const data2 = [
      { count: 100, monthCount: 1, year: 2019 },
      {  count: 55, monthCount: 2, year: 2019 },
      {  count: 99, monthCount: 3, year: 2019 },
      {  count: 130, monthCount: 4, year: 2019 }
    ]
```

I want to get data3 which is `data2 - data1` with its key 
Expected Out put look like that

```
[
    {count: 56, monthCount: 1 },
    {count: 100, monthCount: 2 },
    {count: 60, monthCount: 3 },
    {count: 70, monthCount: 4 }
]
```

Comment: `I subtract first value from demo1 count value and demo2 count value by using the lodash method.` where is that code ?

Comment: Why is the MySQL tag included?  I don't see any Node.js related code to MySQL or see any ascii data table to indicate SQL tables?

Comment: how do you get this result from the input you've provided? in no shape or form 165-55=100 etc.

Comment: as MySQL tag is included, this problem might be (much) more easy solvable in MySQL ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results..

Comment: Why `mySql` tag? Where is `data1`? How do you subtract? What you have tried? Pasting some data and the irrelevant output would not help you here. Show some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subtract `data2 - data1`, then you can do it through vanilla JavaScript. Let me show an example.
Your data:

```
const data1 = [
  { count: 156, monthCount: 1, year: 2018 },
  {  count: 165, monthCount: 2, year: 2018 },
  {  count: 103, monthCount: 3, year: 2018 },
  {  count: 60, monthCount: 4, year: 2018 }
];
const data2 = [
 { count: 100, monthCount: 1, year: 2019 },
 {  count: 55, monthCount: 2, year: 2019 },
 {  count: 99, monthCount: 3, year: 2019 },
 {  count: 130, monthCount: 4, year: 2019 }
];
```

An example:

```
const combined = data1.concat(data2);
console.log(`combined, not calculated`, combined);

const desired = [...combined.reduce((r, {monthCount, count}) => {
const key = monthCount;

  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, {
    count: 0,
    monthCount: monthCount
  });

  if (item.count === 0)
    item.count = -count;
  else
    item.count += +count;

  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(`desired: `, desired)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
    {count: -56, monthCount: 1},
    {count: -110, monthCount: 2},
    {count: -4, monthCount: 3},
    {count: 70, monthCount: 4},
]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks this is work for me... My reputation is less than 15 if increase than definitely I will give you a review and helpful answer.

Comment: @AshishBhangade I am glad that it helped to you. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data1 = [
       { count: 156, monthCount: 1, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 165, monthCount: 2, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 103, monthCount: 3, year: 2018 },
       {  count: 60, monthCount: 4, year: 2018 }
    ]
  const data2 = [
    { count: 100, monthCount: 1, year: 2019 },
    {  count: 55, monthCount: 2, year: 2019 },
    {  count: 99, monthCount: 3, year: 2019 },
    {  count: 130, monthCount: 4, year: 2019 }
  ];

const subtractData = (arrOne, arrTwo) => {
  const newArr = []
  arrOne.forEach((elOne) => {
    arrTwo.forEach((elTwo) => {
      if(elOne.monthCount === elTwo.monthCount){
        const count = Math.abs(Number(elOne.count) - Number(elTwo.count));
        const newObj = {
         ...elOne,
         count
        }
        delete newObj.year;
        newArr.push(newObj)
      }
    })
  })

  return newArr;
}

console.log(subtractData(data1, data2))
```